# Help for translate c# Linq query with 2 group by into vb.net linq query

Tags: linq

### Hello everyone,

I tried and tried to make this query in vb.net, but I can not.
I do not understand if I have to use two groups, and if  so, how do I use them.
This is a query that is in the project - tutorial Tailspin SpyWorks
and should serve to show the 5 most popular products.
I do not understand really how to do.

```
var query = (from ProductOrders in db.OrderDetails
             join SelectedProducts in db.Products on ProductOrders.ProductID
             equals SelectedProducts.ProductID
             group ProductOrders by new
              {
                ProductId = SelectedProducts.ProductID,
                ModelName = SelectedProducts.ModelName
              } into grp
             select new
              {
                ModelName = grp.Key.ModelName,
                ProductId = grp.Key.ProductId,
                Quantity = grp.Sum(o => o.Quantity)
              } into orderdgrp
             where orderdgrp.Quantity > 0
             orderby orderdgrp.Quantity descending
             select orderdgrp).Take(5);
```

I tried to do the translation but I can not find documentation that helps me understand how do I manage two groups.

```
Dim query = (From ProductOrders in db.OrderDetails
                     Join SelectedProducts in db.Products On 
                     ProductOrders.ProductID Equals SelectedProducts.ProductID
                     Group ProductOrders By New With
                       {
                          .ProductId = SelectedProducts.ProductID,
                          .ModelName = SelectedProducts.ModelName 

                      } into grp
```

In fact from now on I can not go on
If someone can please help me out
Thanks a lot
Fabrizio

Answer (score 0):

Im not an expert of VB language, but the following code is syntactically correct:

```
Dim query = (From ProductOrders In Products
                     Join SelectedProducts In SelProducts On ProductOrders.ProductId Equals SelectedProducts.ProductId
                     Group ProductOrders By Key = New With {
                         .ProductId = SelectedProducts.ProductId,
                         .ModelName = SelectedProducts.ModelName
                     } Into grp = Group
                     Select orderdgrp = New With
                     {
                         .ModelName = Key.ModelName,
                         .ProductId = Key.ProductId,
                        .Quantity = grp.Sum(Function(o) o.Quantity)
                     }
                 Where orderdgrp.Quantity > 0
                 Order By orderdgrp.Quantity Descending
                 Select orderdgrp).Take(5)
```

Verify that the query is also semantically correct.